# Regex: Select strings/lines from one point to another point (with many \n)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3, notepad

I want to select all lines starting with `<!-- FLAGS_1 -->` and ending with `<!-- FLAGS -->`

```
<!-- FLAGS_1 -->
              <div class="cautareField">
                <div align="right">

                  <a href="https://mywebsite.com/pentru-un-zeu.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ro.jpg" title="ro" alt="ro" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/fr/pour-un-dieu.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_fr.jpg" title="fr" alt="fr" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/love-tender.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_en.jpg" title="en" alt="en" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/es/una-oracion-por-un-dios.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_es.jpg" title="es" alt="es" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/pt/uma-para-um-deus.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_pt.jpg" title="pt" alt="pt" width="28" height="19" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/ar/love-tender.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ae.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ar" alt="ar" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/zh/love-tender.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_zh.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="zh" alt="zh" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/hi/love-tender.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_hi.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="hi" alt="hi" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/de/love-tender.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_de.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="de" alt="de" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/ru/love-tender.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ru.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ru" alt="ru" /></a>
</div>
</div>
<!-- FLAGS -->
```

I try many regex combination, but not working:

SEARCH: `<!-- FLAGS_1 -->(\s\n.*?)<!-- FLAGS -->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<!-- FLAGS_1 -->(?:(?!<!-- FLAGS -->).)+<!-- FLAGS -->`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<!-- FLAGS_1 -->        # literally
                    # Tempered Greedy Token
    (?:                     # non capture group
        (?!<!-- FLAGS -->)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't <!-- FLAGS --> in the matched string
        .                       # any character
    )+                      # end group, must appear 1 or more times
<!-- FLAGS -->          # literally
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple find string: `<!-- FLAGS_1 -->\r\n.*?\r\n<!-- FLAGS -->`

Where:

- `\r\n` : end of line
- `.*?` : any string, no greedy search

Ensure that "Regular expression" is checked, as well as ". matches newline".

Answer (score 0):

try this

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<!-- FLAGS_1 -->[\s\S]*?<!-- FLAGS -->[\s\S]*?`